# adding a text between two divs html

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

i have a html page in which i am showing two images ... i want to add the text between the images.. at the moment the images are displaying like this

[image]

i want to do something like this

[image]

how can i add a text or small image of **VS** here in the middle. 
here is  my code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Gd5Bg/

i am writing a small bit of code here because stack is not giving me the permission to add a jsfiddle link without the code here

```
 <div class="image-galery">
    <a class="group" rel="group1" href="img/4_b.jpg">
      <img src="img/4_b.jpg" />
    </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your site/page are built in Bootstrap.  This affects how people will approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="span5 galery" style="float:left">
     .......
</div>
<div style="float:left;position:relative;top:150px;left:5px;">vs</div>
<div class="span5 galery" style="float:left">
     .......
</div>
```

Comment: One problem with this solution is that it does not dynamically allow rendering of the page and depends on hard coding the size of the images, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Put your elements in a table. Then use

```
 <td style="vertical-align:middle"> ... </td>
```

To center everything vertically.